# Interference with <button> tag

Tags: javascript, button, search, calendar, blogs

I seem to be having problems with my search and calendar buttons. They're using the same function which is from my blog archive buttons.

```
    <script>
    $('button').each(function() {

      /* "each" in jQuery lets us apply what's inside here to each button individually without having to give them each their own names. Imagine this code going down the line and repeating everything below for each of the buttons. */

      var $thisButton = $(this);

      /* To refer to the individual button inside of this section we can use $(this), but to try and make the rest of this more clear, I'm going to rename $(this) to $thisButton */

      $thisButton.click(function() {

        var $thisButtonsDropdown = $thisButton.siblings();

        /* Sibling here means "on the same level as the button." We need to do this to find the section of months or links that matches this button we clicked, so that we slide up/down the right one--the one we want is the one that is next to it, its sibling. */

        /* This part should be a little familiar! */
        if ($thisButtonsDropdown.is(':visible')) {
          $thisButtonsDropdown.slideUp();
          $thisButton.removeClass('flip');
        } else {
          $thisButtonsDropdown.slideDown();
          $thisButton.addClass('flip');
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Here's the code to my search and calendar buttons :

```
/* Start JS Calendar */

.calendar-wrapper {
  width:175px;
  height:175px;
  margin:3em auto;
  margin-left:20px;
  padding:2em;
  border:0px solid @calendar-border;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:none;
  position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:100;
  cursor:text;

}
table {
  clear:both;
  width:208px;
  height:100px;
  border:5px double #000;
  border-radius:0px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  color:@calendar-color;
  background:white;
  position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
  cursor:text;
}
td {
  font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana, Trebuchet MS, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans;
  height:8px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border-right:1px solid black;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  width:100% / 7;
  cursor:text;
}
td.not-current {
  color:#ccc;
  font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana, Trebuchet MS, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans;
  cursor:text;
  font-size:17px;
}
td.normal {}
td.today {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#98d6e3;
  font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana, Trebuchet MS, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans;
  text-shadow:none;
  cursor:text;
}

thead td {
  border:none;
  color:#6871b8;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-shadow:0px 2px 1px #aaa;
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana, Trebuchet MS, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans;
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding-left:6px;
  padding-right:6px;
  padding-top:3px;
  width:275px;
  cursor:text;
  z-index:0px;
}

#btnPrev {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:rgba(153, 159, 207, 1);
  font-family:Laila, Segoe UI Light, Arial, Segoe UI, Georgia, Verdana;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:1em;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:29px;
  z-index:250;
}
#btnNext {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:rgba(153, 159, 207, 1);
  font-family:Laila, Segoe UI Light, Arial, Segoe UI, Georgia, Verdana;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:1em;
  float:right;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:227px;
  z-index:250;
}
#btnPrev:hover {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  font-size:1em;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:Laila, Segoe UI Light, Arial, Segoe UI, Georgia, Verdana;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 2px #fff, 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  text-transform:none;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
  color:white;
  z-index:100;

}

#btnNext:hover {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  font-size:1em;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family:Laila, Arial, Segoe UI, Georgia, Verdana;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 2px #fff, 0px 0px 2px #fff;
  text-transform:none;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
  color:white;
  z-index:100;
}


.days {
  color:#7b6f7d;
  background:#fff;
  cursor:text;
  font-family:Overpass, Arial, Verdana, Trebuchet MS, Segoe UI, Lucida Sans;
}

/* End JS Calendar */
```

```
<div class="calendar-wrapper">
  <button id="btnPrev" type="button">&#10210;</button>
      <button id="btnNext" type="button">&#10211;</button>
  <div id="divCal"></div>
</div>
```

My guess is because of the fact that they use the same  tag, tho I'm not sure. Does anyone know what may be going on, and what is going on for sure?

Comment: Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Yea my guess is no wants to help you because you didn't bring whats wrong with your code and what are your expected results. So update the post and will help you in seconds.

Comment: @Mortimer hey. I actually got it all fixed up. Turns out that I had to move down the search box n all its code down just before the </body> tag. Now all that's left not working is my calendar's buttons for some reason.